# Cloud Functions: How to Insert Data into BigQuery when a file is Uploaded into a GCS Bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am new to GCP Cloud Functions, and I am trying to add a function to my existing code, which will insert data into BigQuery when a specific file is uploaded into my GCS Bucket.

I am unsure how to write a function to accomplish this task - like, do I need to write a function that will check to see if the file exists first?

So far, I have written the following Cloud Function, which inserts data into BigQuery:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

def conn_to_bigquery(request):

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """

"""

query_job = client.query(query)
```

Check if file exists:

```
name = 'file_i_want_to_check.txt'   
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = 'my_bucket_name'
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
stats = storage.Blob(bucket=bucket, name=name).exists(storage_client)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a [Cloud Storage Trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) when you deploy a `Cloud Function`  :

```bash
gcloud functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME \
--gen2 \
--trigger-event-filters="type=EVENT_TYPE" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket=YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET" \
...
```

This example uses `Cloud Function V2`.
You can use event arc event type with : `google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized`, check the link I shared above.

For the `Cloud Function`, you can use [Cloud Event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions) :

```py
import functions_framework

# Register a CloudEvent function with the Functions Framework
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def conn_to_bigquery(cloud_event):
  # Your code here
  # Access the CloudEvent data payload via cloud_event.data
  
  client = bigquery.Client()

  query = """
  """

  query_job = client.query(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, to check the file exists, do I not need to add something like this? See main post for code.

Comment: You don't need to check if the file exists, because when the file will be uploaded to GCS, it will trigger the Cloud Function. The file necessarily exists in this case.

Comment: I see - though, if you look at the answer below, does that accomplish the same thing?

Comment: What do you want to do in the Cloud Function ? I ask this because it’s not clear in your question.

Comment: You have answered my question, but I got confused, as I thought that I needed to add addditional code in my file to check if the file exists or not. Do I just use this code as it is? ```def conn_to_bigquery(cloud_event):```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770442/gcp-cloud-function-to-load-the-file-that-trigger-the-object-finalize-event-type

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code , follow indentation as per image added bellow

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
"""Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
Args:
     event (dict): Event payload.
     context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
"""
#imports
from google.cloud import logging
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client() 


file = event
print(file)   
print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")
print(f"Bucket name: {file['bucket']}.")

file_name = file['name'] #get the filename which triggered cloudfunction
bucket_name = file['bucket'] #get bucketname

table_id = "<your_projectid>.<your_dataset>.<your_tableid>" #Fill your table_id which was created in previous step
uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name,file_name) #automatically the uri is generated here by using filename and bucketname.
mapping     q
 
    
#Fill the required configaration details
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.skip_leading_rows=0
job_config.source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
job_config.schema=destination_table.schema

    
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri( uri, table_id, job_config=job_config  )  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - thanks for this; though, what line would the SQL code go?

Comment: If you want to upload csv file ( Which triggered the cloud function ). you no need to use sql query.  I mean GCS CSV to Big query .  if you want to execute query follow bellow code                                                                                                                       client = bigquery.Client()

  query = """
  """

  query_job = client.query(query)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).